# How to make dropdown multiselect

Tags: sapui5

I want to make this drop down multi select. Please help!! I should be able to select more than one option from the drop down.

```
<m:ComboBox value="All" editable="true" enabled="true" visible="true" width="50%" valueState="None"  maxWidth="100%">
    <m:items>
        <core:Item text="UI5" enabled="true"/>
        <core:Item text="S/4 HANA" enabled="true"/>
        <core:Item text="Java" enabled="true"/>
        <core:Item text=".Net" enabled="true"/>
        <core:Item text="Testing" enabled="true"/>
        <core:Item text="ABAP" enabled="true"/>
        <core:Item text="UX" enabled="true"/>
    </m:items>
</m:ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

use multicombobox control.
Here's an example
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.MultiComboBox/preview

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score -1):

ComboBox's do not support multi-select. Use a ListBox with `multiselect=1` (simple) or `multiselect=2` (extended)

Edit: Not C#. Use the property `allowMultiSelect`

See the [documentation](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.ListBox.html#getAllowMultiSelect) for more details on this property.

Comment: sap.ui.commons is deprecated